# CSV write to file starting with comment lines

Tags: python, python-2.7

I need to create a file that contains csv data (or tsv, rather) prepended by several commented (via "#") lines (processing instructions for a third party program).

What I have tried was to open a template file with comments in append mode and write csvrows to it:

```
...
with open('template.txt', 'a+') as csvfile:
        for record in records:
            csvWriter = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter='\t',quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
            csvWriter.writerow([record['Id'], record['Email']])
....
```

This does not work (no matter which flags I use to open the file). It does not overwrite the commented lines, but it skips as many csv rows as there are comments.

So this is apparently not how to do it. So what would be the proper way in Python (2.7) to create a file that mixes non-csv data and csv data (I want my csv fields properly quoted etc, so I do not want to use a simple write operation for my csv rows) ?

Comment: " it skips as many csv rows as there are comments." Really? not for me. Can't really imagine how. What OS? (not that @pgy's answer is any less correct, but the above actually worked for me on linux).

Comment: Yes, really. I accept that I am doing something stupid, but the problem is there. This is python 2.7 on Mac Os 10.11.2 and the template file is created within the same python script (copied from another file). Is there any more info I can give that makes this more answerable ?

Answer (score 3):

You don't have to create a new `csv.writer` every iteration, it is just a wrapper around `file.write`.

```
import csv
with open("template.txt", "wt") as fp:

    fp.write("# first commented line\n")
    fp.write("# second commented line\n")

    writer = csv.writer(fp)

    for record in records:
        writer.writerow([record["Id"], record["Email"]])

    fp.write("# a commented line among the records\n")

    for record in more_records:
        writer.writerow([record["Id"], record["Email"]])
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing out that I don't need to create a new csvfilewriter on every new iteration. That was stupid of me. But I assumed that csvwriter would quote csv field correctly (and a simple write wouldn't) if they contained delimiters and quotes ? If not, what is the csvwriter for ?

Comment: `csv.writer` is a wrapper around `file.write` that manages delimiters and quotes (if needed), but nothing stops you from using the underlying (i.e. the wrapped) file descriptor.